# Error getting output of json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, arraylist

I can't get this code working

http://pastebin.com/Y05qySCb

i just want to submit the callback URL and address and get the result (it is a bitcoin address)
cloud anyone fix it for me
i will really thank you all

Comment: You'll need to supply the output of `file_get_contents($url)`, my guess is that it isn't a valid JSON, or `input_address` isn't an property field. You can also try `var_dump($result)` to always see an output (NULL if it's actually empty, i.e JSON not valid, or too deep).

Comment: look it is a valid json u can see [link](https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&callback=http://45.79.174.191/callback.php&invoice_id=1395031243&address=15WpZp9MpTAxyR4Q73nFCaHUH8pRJX1mzL)
i dont know why i cant get the output

Comment: I just ran your code with the URL provided and it worked fine. So I think it's an issue with settings. Check if [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled in your php.ini.

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/3wa8TW3U) is the entire code could you check it please maybe you can find the error

Comment: Are you sure that's the code? It looks like part of a class, did you delete some important parts?

Comment: yeh only need these actually i only need the part that submit the info's to blockchain and get the address back and [this](http://pastebin.com/gcUKyMVr) is the complete class